ASP.NET MVC error 403.14 - forbidden on default page
When I'm debugging the app, it will start correctly looking for /Home/Index, however, when I publish to the server, I get

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

I'm not entirely sure what I have to do so I'm reaching out for a bit of help.
My Global.asax.cs has RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes like this:
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
}

And my RouteConfig looks like this:
public class RouteConfig
{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
}

I've even added to my web.config:
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>

I don't know what I'm possibly missing.

Thank you for the edit, it looks much better.  I also just found my answer.  I did not have asp.net 4.8 installed on my IIS webserver, I only had .NEt Extensibility 4.8

This is supposed to be part of a comment not an answer, please remove this, and add this in comments section

No, that was the issue, that was the answer
